# Background image in css and giving it parallax

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I have question. I am using materialize CSS. And I tried parallax with the html 
`<img class="parallax">` tag but is there a way to give you're background image in CSS but also making it parallax.

My Example code:

Content html:

```
    <div class="row parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax">
        <div class="intro headerBackground">
            <h1 class="grey-text text-lighten-5">Data</h1>
            <h5 class="grey lighten-4 grey-text text-darken-1">Data</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Content CSS:

```
.intro
{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 13%;
    padding-bottom: 13%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.intro h1
{
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.intro h5
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.headerBackground{
    height:800px;
    background-image:url('images');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please Try:-**

```
<div class="row parallax-container">
<div class="parallax headerBackground">
    <div class="intro">
        <h1 class="grey-text text-lighten-5">Data</h1>
        <h5 class="grey lighten-4 grey-text text-darken-1">Data</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope your problem it will solve when you will be replace the code :)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: Please again update and check 

.headerBackground{
 background-attachment:fixed;
}